# How to keep socket alive in ios?

Tags: ios, sockets, background, voip

I'm doing a VOIP project on iPhone. I have the problem to keep the socket alive.
I already configured one socket for VOIP usage, and set `kCFStreamNetworkServiceTypeVoIP` for `CFReadStreamRef` and `CFWriteStreamRef`.

- When my app runs in the foreground and I don't do any action, after 1 minute iPhone will sleep, black screen. My socket is **still connected** to the server.
- But when my app runs in the foreground I press home button, and don't do any action, about 1 minute iPhone will sleep, then my socket **disconnects** from server.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

First, have you read [Tips for Developing a VoIP App](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html)? From your description, it sounds like you haven't set `UIBackgroundModes` to `voip`. You also likely will need to configure a keep alive handler.

Comment: I already set UIBackgroundModes to voip and audio. 
The problem is when my app not run in forceground, and iphone go to sleep. my socket disconnected.

Thanks for you reply.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue, I am having the same problem of the socket going after 1 minute on a different mobile OS.

Comment: can this be fixed without using trick like use audio in background or voip or location service??

Comment: You cannot keep a socket alive while in the background. It's forbidden by Apple and the OS will kill you. You *can* register as a VoIP app (if you are a VoIP app), and register for a socket that the OS will listen to and wake you up when there's data on it.